# JQuery create expanding div on navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Take this snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.test {
  color: white;
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  transition: height ease 1s;
}

.test:hover {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">Hover Here</div>
</div>
```

A simple div inside a container which expands to 100% when hovered over. What I am trying to make is very simular to this, but in a navigation menu (similar to http://www.mineplex.com/).

When a user hovers over the **container div** (not the main box itself) I need the **main div** to expand from **0% to 100%** in height.

I have tried using JQuery to solve this using a ".hovered" class with no luck. How can one code this?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So, what do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's a demonstration:**

**Similarities between both the code snippets:**

- The containers make use of flex display to make a responsive navbar container, with each of its items spanning a width of 20% (which can be adjusted).
- Each of the items (with relative positioning) has two sub containers (with absolute positioning), the first being overlay which we're making use for getting the blue transitioning background(z-index:1) and the second which has a fixed text on the front (z-index:2).
- Now, the z-index makes sure that the overlay will be transitioned at the back and text will be fixed in the front, another thing to keep in mind is since we're transitioning it from the bottom up, we set the bottom:0 on the overlay class as well as height:0%;.
- On hovering , we transition the height from 0% to 100%.

**Differences between both the code snippets:**

- In the first snippet, we're transitioning each item on hover by making use of `.items:hover .overlay`.
- Whereas in the second snippet, we're transitioning every item when the container is hovered instead of individual items by using `.container:hover > *.items> .overlay` ( ">" is a direct child selector ).

**First:** Hovering each item individually to expand the overlay.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background: gray;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.items {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.item-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.items:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">Home</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">About</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">Other</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Second:** When the user hovers over the container, expanding all the overlays.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background: gray;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.items {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.item-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.container:hover > *.items> .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">Home</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">About</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="item-text">Other</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And @DavidThomas I'd say I provided a solution , actually two to that unclear question. And that's why the comment above if you noticed that, if that's what the OP referred to, that's why the two demonstrations. And talking about explanations, I do explain all of my solutions before you voted it down, but to a question to which the OP does know how to achieve a specific solution, it becomes unclear to exactly what they require until a demonstration is presented. Thank you

Comment: Fair enough, and thank you for providing the explanation; while you may disagree with my down-voting I prefer to down-vote incomplete answers and then retract those down-votes should the answer be completed; while you may explain all your answers not everyone does, and my voting pattern is influenced by that experience. Incidentally my down-vote here was retracted. If you feel a question is unclear (and this one certainly is/was), consider leaving comments to ask for clarity. Sorry if I seem preachy or patronising; that's not my intent I promise!

Comment: @DavidThomas I get the down-vote, but I wanted to explain myself as to why there was no explanation. And I know that most people don't explain their code and I ask them to explain or just down-vote right away if it doesn't match the OP's criteria (with the comment saying so). And I do always modify/update my answers depending on the OP's actual requirements (because most questions are unclear as to what they specifically need or fail in trying to explain). That's why the two demonstrations. And it's alright, I don't hold it against you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

ul li{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

ul li a{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

ul li a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
ul li a:hover:after{
  animation: bounce 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0% {height: 0%}
  20% { height: 100%}
  55% { height: 95%}
  100% {height: 100%}
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Saepe, asperiores!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Vitae, expedita?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dicta, quo.</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sed, et.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please explain what you modified to help solve the problem so that others can also learn from this example. What is it that you did that solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i wrote some code

```
//html

<ul>
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


//This is sass 

ul {
  list-style:none;
  background:red;

  li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;


    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 0%;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background:blue;
      transition: height ease-in-out 0.5s;
    } 

    a {
      z-index:2;
      position:relative;
      color:white;
    }

    &:hover {
       &:before {
          height: 100%;
       }
    }
  }
}
```